# Zero is least element of ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

*Definition.* An ordinal is a well-ordered set $X$ such that for all $x\in X$, $(−∞, x) = x$.

Lemma. Zero is least element of ordinal.

Proof. Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal. Let $x$ be least element of $\alpha$. So, $x=x\cap\alpha=\emptyset$. Thus $\emptyset$ is least element of $\alpha$, that is $0$ is least element of $\alpha$.

**My questions: Why $x\cap\alpha=\emptyset$?**

Comment: I'm assuming $(-\infty, x)$ means $\{y \in X : y < x\}$? I haven't seen that notation before but it makes sense.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Where did you get the notation $(-\infty,x)$?

Comment: if $α$ is an ordinal and $x, y\in α$, $y < x$ if and only if $y\in x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is an ordinal and $x\in\alpha$ then, according to the definition you just gave, $x=(-\infty,x)$ and so $x\cap\alpha=(-\infty,x)\cap\alpha.$ If $x$ is the **least** element of $\alpha,$ then $(-\infty,x)
\cap\alpha=\emptyset.$

Comment: Actually,Why not  $x\cap\alpha=x$?

Comment: I didn't understant really why $x\cap\alpha=\emptyset$.

Comment: Do you understand why $(-\infty,x)\cap\alpha=\emptyset$? Maybe I'm not understanding your notation. What does $(-\infty,x)$ mean?

Comment: I mean that if $α$ is an ordinal and $x, y\in\alpha$, $y < x$ if and only if $y\in x$.

Comment: I think, since $\left( -\infty ,x\right)\subseteq\alpha$,  $\left( -\infty ,x\right)\cap\alpha=\left( -\infty ,x\right)$. But not true. Why? I didn't understand.

Comment: I don't understand really why $x\cap\alpha=\emptyset$.

Comment: What does $(-\infty,x)$ mean? is $(-\infty,x)=\{y:y\lt x\}$?

Comment: So, if $x$ is the ***LEAST*** element of $\alpha,$ then $$x=(-\infty,x)=\{y:y\lt x\}=\emptyset?$$

Comment: Okey. I understood. So, if $x$ any element of $\alpha$ then what can we say $x\cap\alpha$?

Comment: Can we say $x\cap\alpha=x$?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I understand that definition of ordinal to mean: $\alpha$ is well-ordered so that, for each element $x\in\alpha$, $$x=\{y\in\alpha:y\lt x\}.$$ So of course $$x\in\alpha\implies x\subseteq\alpha\implies x\cap\alpha=x.$$